# catching exceptions while following SOLID principles in winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

```
 public async Task<StorageFile> GetFile( string fileName )
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
        var _folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
          var _file = await _folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return _file;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //notify user about the exception.
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the only method in my class that simply retrieves a file from local storage. I want to notify the user about any exception. If i try to do a message box in the catch statement it would be braking the solid's first rule of single responsibility.

How should I setup the class that my other handler class can catch the exceptions and take the required action? My first thoughts were event handlers, but is there any better technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public async Task<StorageFile> GetFile( string fileName )
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
        var _folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
          var _file = await _folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return _file;
        }
        catch
        {
           throw;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Instead of catching the Exception here simply throw it up to the controller that called it. Be sure to have a try{}catch{} surrounding the call to this method and you can handle the Exception there (i.e. show a message box).

Comment: Yes, let's put a try/catch with nothing but a rethrow in it... ;)

Comment: so i should throw the exception again and catch it later from the other class into which i want to inject this class .. thank you

Comment: I agree with @KyleW use try...finally or no exception handling to achieve this. mac has  a good approach otherwise.